# Sync Status Exchange Calendar

Tags: sync, calendar, accounts

Due to inconsistence of the exchange calendar sync at work, Id  like to have some kind of widget or notification or whatever is easily doable, to see when the calendar was synchronised properly the last time. The IT guy seems not really interested in fixing the problem, considering its hard to find the problem probably, and I really don't like missing stuff. 
I already searched for some time and haven't found any apps or widgets in the play store. 
Do u guys know if there's a way to do this?
Thank you in advance for your help.